# jQuery ajax call failing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm having some issues with jQuery AJAX calls. I'm by no means an expert but I know jQuery enough to get by with simple tasks.

Here is my code -

```
var id = 123;
    var url = "/test.aspx?id=" + id;
            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                alert(1);
            });
```

The problem is that the alert(1) is not getting hit. When I check for [domain]/test.aspx?id=123 manually, I'm getting JSON data back. What am I doing wrong here or how can I diagnose the issue here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: As the url suggest, this is not a cross domain request, right?

Comment: You could add `.fail(function() { console.log( "error" ); })` to your function to check for failure.

Comment: BTW, you are talking about nested ajax requests but posted only the nested one. Are you sure this code is reached?

Comment: Check your console: You can follow the request at network, probably the error is at the /test

Comment: Using any modern browser you should be able to open up the "Developer Tools" and look at the network tab for errors. You usually need to open this tab and re-load your page in order to see something. I think in IE you actually need to click "Start Capture" or something. Anyways once you do this you will be able to see if (#1) The call is ever being made and (#2) Is the call succeeding, what type of response the server sends. Good Luck! If you like this answer then I can post is as an answer below.

Comment: roasted - There were no cross domain requests
putvande - Thanks for the advice. I narrowed it down to a data type issue.
Jonathan - my request always worked in the browser but jquery failed to parse it due to no data type being specified. It was trying to use some default type. I specified JSON type and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little strange but I had to specify a data type of JSON in the request.

var id = 123;
var url = "/echo/json/";
$.getJSON(url, "json", function (data) {
    alert("hello");
});

I got the idea of JSON from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/. The example on this page was for PlainObject. The url in my code was trying to parse JSON as PlainObject but failing. I used .success and .error after closing bracket of getJSON to figure out the issue. To see how success and error can be used scroll to the bottom of the jquery.com link.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works perfectly fine. Here is a JSfiddle example to test it (using the echo service):

```
var id = 123;
var url = "/echo/json/";
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QyfCF/1/

Comment: It worked fine for you. For me, I had to specify a data type of JSON for it to work. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem coming from somewhere other than the code you've provided.  To troubleshoot, I'd try doing something like this...

```
var id = 123;
var url = "/test.aspx?id=" + id;
console.log("before");
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  console.log("inside");
});
console.log("after");
```

That way you can see whether the code actually ever gets to the json request because you'll see "before" in the console, you can see whether it gets inside because you'll see "inside" in the console, etc.

Also, it's possible that the url your passing into `$.getJSON` isn't the correct url.  You might wanna try it without the slash beforehand, or possibly pass in the full url to make sure you're referencing the right place.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tried before and after and figured that the issue was with getJSON alone. I used .error and .success and figured it was a data type issue. See my answer for fix.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your JSON is valid JSON, e.g. by running it though [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).
JQuery's `.getJSON()` and `.ajax()` silently fail when the requested JSON is not valid.

Comment: The JSON was valid. It was just that the function wasn't able to parse and I had to specify it. Check my answer.